# Custom theme update - Unauthorized

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been trying to make my custom theme auto update and I've tried to use this update checker: https://github.com/YahnisElsts/plugin-update-checker

Everything works fine except There is a basic authorization on my server and username and password is needed to access the url where my latest theme zip file is stored and when I try to update the theme I get the error: **An error occurred while updating YOUR-THEME: Download failed. Unauthorized**

Is there a way to make it work with basic authorization (it's working without it). Maybe some filter to pass the credentials?

Thanks.

Comment: If this is a custom theme I pressume it's not in the Wordpress repository?